# Dataframe to sql without Sql Alchemy engine

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe

```
id    value     name
1      100       sam
2      766       abc
3      234       qqq
4      435       ppp
5      345       mmm
```

i want to save this table into sql server database into table 'tab1'

i can do `df.to_sql()` but my program hangs when i'm doing this.(im using django).

is there any other way to save dataframe to sql server without using sql alchemy engine?

Comment: Can you post a corresponding code for creating SQL Alchemy connection and `DataFrame.to_sql` call?

Comment: df.to_sql('tab1',engine,index = 'False')

Comment: how did you create `engine`?

Comment: does this have to be be a pandas-only answer? Would converting the dataframe into another data structure and send it to SQL another way be viable?

Comment: @MaxU i created a function where i passed parameters and returned engine object. `sql_engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://" + str(uid) + ":" + str(pwd) + "@" + str(driver))
        return sql_engine.connect()`

Comment: @MattR Can be converted from pandas to other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to avoid using SQL Alchemy, but it's not supported (deprecated) by Pandas.

Here is an excerpt from the `pd.to_sql` docstring:

> **con** : SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (legacy mode)
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
>
> library. **If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.**