# Why are Pandas and GeoPandas able to read a database table using a DBAPI (psycopg2) connection but have to rely on SQLAlchemy to write one?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, geopandas

## Context

I just get into trouble while trying to do some I/O operations on some databases from a [`Python3`](https://www.python.org/) script.

When I want to [connect](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) to a database, I habitually use [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) in order to handle the [connections](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection) and [cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor).

My data are usually stored as [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [`DataFrames`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and/or [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org)'s equivalent [`GeoDataFrames`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html).

## Difficulties

### In order to **read** data **from** a database table;

#### Using [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

I can rely on its [`.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) methods which takes as a parameter `con`, as stated in the doc:

```
con : SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database str URI
        or DBAPI2 connection (fallback mode)'
        Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
        library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported. The user is responsible
        for engine disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy connectable. See
        `here <https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html>`_
```

#### Using [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org):

I can rely on its [`.read_postigs()`](https://geopandas.org/io.html?highlight=read_postgis) methods which takes as a parameter `con`, as stated in the doc:

```
con : DB connection object or SQLAlchemy engine
        Active connection to the database to query.
```

### In order to **write** data **to** a database table;

#### Using [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

I can rely on the [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) methods which takes as a parameter `con`, as stated in the doc:

```
con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection
        Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
        library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects. The user
        is responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy
        connectable See `here                 <https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html>`_
```

#### Using [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org):

I can rely on the `.to_sql()` methods (which directly relies on the `Pandas` [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) which takes as a parameter `con`, as stated in the doc:

```
con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection
        Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
        library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects. The user
        is responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy
        connectable See `here                 <https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html>`_
```

From here, I easily understand that [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org) is built on [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) especially for its [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) object, which is, shortly, a special [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) that can handle geographic data.

But I'm wondering why do [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org) has the ability to directly takes a [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) connection as an argument and not [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and if it is planned for the latter?

And why is it neither the case for one nor the other when it comes to **writing** data?
I would like (as probably many of others<sup>1,2</sup>) to directly give them a [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) [connections](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection) argument instead of relying on [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html).
Because even is this tool is really great, it makes me use two different frameworks to connect to my database and thus handle two different connection strings (and I personally prefer the way [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org/) handles the parameters expansion from a dictionary to build a connection string properly such as; `psycopg2.connect(**dict_params)` vs [URL](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/a3145cffe2bdce393795cf9cd51605227be00b7f/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py#L26) injection as explained here for example: [Is it possible to pass a dictionary into create_engine function in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895457/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-dictionary-into-create-engine-function-in-sqlalchemy)).

## Workaround

1. I was first creating my connection string with [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) from a dictionary of parameters this way:

   ```
   connParams = ("user={}", "password={}", "host={}", "port={}", "dbname={}")
   conn = ' '.join(connParams).format(*dict_params.values())
   ```
2. Then I figured out it was better and more pythonic this way:

   ```
   conn = psycopg2.connect(**dict_params)
   ```
3. Which I finally replaced by this, so that I can interchangeably use it to build either a [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) [connections](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection), or a `SQLAlchemy` engine:

   ```
   def connector():
       return psycopg2.connect(**dict_params)
   ```

   **a)** Initialize a [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org) [connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection) is now done by:

   ```
   conn = connector()
   curs = conn.cursor()
   ```

   **b)** And initialize a [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html) by:

   ```
   engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)
   ```

(or with any of your flavored `db+driver`)

This is well documented here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args
and here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine

---

[1] [Dataframe to sql without Sql Alchemy engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979102/dataframe-to-sql-without-sql-alchemy-engine)
[2] [How to write data frame to Postgres table without using SQLAlchemy engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664141/how-to-write-data-frame-to-postgres-table-without-using-sqlalchemy-engine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the main reason why `to_sql` needs a SQLAlchemy `Connectable` (`Engine` or `Connection`) object is that `to_sql` needs to be able to create the database table if it does not exist or if it needs to be replaced. Early versions of pandas worked exclusively with DBAPI connections, but I suspect that when they were adding new features to `to_sql` they found themselves writing a lot of database-specific code to work around the quirks of the various DDL implementations.

On realizing that they were duplicating a lot of logic that was already in SQLAlchemy they likely decided to "outsource' all of that complexity to SQLAlchemy itself by simply accepting an `Engine`/`Connection` object and using SQLAlchemy's (database-independent) SQL Expression language to create the table.

> it makes me use two different frameworks to connect to my database

No, because `.read_sql_query()` also accepts a SQLAlchemy `Connectable` object so you can just use your SQLAlchemy connection for both reading and writing.

Comment: That's correct. Writing data to a database needs a lot of database-flavor-specific code, which is handled by SQLAlchemy. Reading data (at least when based on a SELECT query) just receives the result sets and can be done more generally.

Comment: Indeed, but the question I'm asking myself is more; what does `SQLAlchemy` have that `psycopg2` doesn't? I have the feeling that SQLAlchemy depends on `psycopg2` (or other database frameworks) to communicate with the database because when constructing a string for an  `engine`, one can specify the database driver, such as `('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')`, hence why not directly use the database driver (i.e. `psycopg2` in that case) in the `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` method?

Comment: DBAPI interface layers like psycopg2 are written to the [DBAPI specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) which is mainly concerned with sending arbitrary SQL statements to the database server and receiving the results. They are quite capable of sending a `CREATE TABLE` statement to the database but they do not have any idea of how to construct such a statement because it's "not their job"; that's for somebody else to worry about, and for pandas that "somebody else" is SQLAlchemy.