# Sqlalchemy Teradata ODBC 17.00 to_sql QVCI error CAST CLOB type to DATE

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata, clob, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to use pandas `to_sql` to an existing table in Teradata database but I got this QVCI error. After some research online, I upgraded my ODBC driver to 17.00 but I still get the same error.

Existing Table:

[image]

I am using `sqlalchemy_teradata`

Here is the code:
`a_df.to_sql(name='TEST_LA_TEMP', con=engine, schema='DB', if_exists='replace', index=False)`

I then tried to specify the types but got the same error.

```
from sqlalchemy.types import INTEGER, VARCHAR, Date

a_df.head()
a_df.to_sql(name='TEST_LA_TEMP', con=engine_ldap, schema='DB', if_exists='replace', index=False
            , dtype={'id': INTEGER,
                     'p_name': VARCHAR(20),
                     'dept': VARCHAR(20),
                     'update_date': Date})
```

ERROR:

```
DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (9719, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-9719)QVCI feature is disabled.')
[SQL: SELECT * 
FROM dbc.ColumnsQV 
WHERE DatabaseName (NOT CASESPECIFIC) = CAST(? as VARCHAR(128)) (NOT CASESPECIFIC) AND TableName=?]
[parameters: ('DB', 'TEST_LA_TEMP')]
```

When I use the same code to import to an NEW (non-existing) table, it works fine but returns `CLOB` as datatype for most columns

[image]

I then tried to CAST `CLOB` Types to the correct Types but it said `CLOBs can only be converted to CHAR TO VARCHAR` missing my `update_date` column.

I can get it working if I use `if_exists='append'` instead, and then drop and create table again. but I still want to understand why and how to resolve these errors.

Questions:

1. What is the syntax to enable QVCI directly for Teradata?
2. Is there a way to CAST CLOB to DATE? How?
3. Why `if_exists='replace'` depends on QVCI but not `if_exists='append'`?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Don't enable QVCI, it's unsupported, and current Teradata drivers would not reference it. Perhaps you have both old and new driver installed it's still picking up the old one (e.g. you may need explicit driver= in your connection string). Consider using  _teradatasqlalchemy_ vs _sqlalchemy_teradata plus ODBC_. 2)  You can CAST first to VARCHAR then to DATE. 3) For "replace" the code is apparently trying to save the existing column attributes so it can DROP and re-CREATE under the covers.

Comment: In the future please limit each SO "question" to a single issue. To control the data types of the columns see the `dtype` argument in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) for `to_sql`. And as for your third question see the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150030/2144390).

Comment: It's possible that the connection is still tied to the old driver, just like Fred said. QVCI issue has been addressed since v16.20 going forward. I would delete DSN and recreate it, making sure you link it to the proper driver. Also, make sure you are doing it on the machine that actually runs your code. If you connect to DB from an app server, your driver has to be updated there, and not on the client box.